# Vertical rulers to show tab/indentation using Highlight JS

Tags: javascript, highlight.js

I'm using Highlight JS for my code on a documentation website. I want to add in vertical rulers to show the tab/indentation levels, like so:

[image]

The while lines on the code. Is it possible to pull this off in any way? Thanks for any help.